# Best option for adding labels to list items for print/export?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Small school project where I am attempting to add labels to a very long list which is obtained from sql connection. The list obtains for example, cell1 -cell3, then goes to the next selected row. It is from a GUI interface for user selection, but the GUI side passes a list of selected row items.

So with a much shorter version of the list, for example:

```
my_list = ['apple', 'carrot', 'chicken', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'ham']
labels = ['Fruit', 'Vegatable', 'Meat']
```

What is a good solution for adding a label that is iterated over every nth item of my_list, and appends the labels, so output comes to something like:

```
Fruit       : apple
Vegetable   : carrot
Meat        : chicken
Fruit       : orange
Vegetable   : broccoli
Meat        : ham
```

-or-

```
Fruit     Vegatable    Meat
apple     carrot       chicken
orange    broccoli     ham
```

I tried to create a second list of Labels, but it ends the label list and does not continue once the list with labels runs out. 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I also attempted a very repetitive process of breaking them into sections of 3 using something like:

```
print("".join(["".join(my_list[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3)]))
```

But I can't figure out how to get a header to each item.
then some very ugly method jsut to get the output:

```
for item in (my_list[::3]):
    print(str(labels[0]) + "\t" + item)
for item in (my_list[1::3]):
    print(str(labels[1]) + "\t" + item)
for item in (my_list[2::3]):
    print(str(labels[2]) + "\t" + item)
```

1) What is a good option for combining these?

2) Is there a faster speed alternative to combining two lists?  The actual list I am trying to work with is quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate the lists, then split one every nth item using `list1 [x % 3]`. Then format them with `.formt` to the spacing needed.

```
for idx, value in enumerate(my_list):
    i = labels[idx % 3]
    j = value
    print('{:12} : {:3}'.format(i, j))
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability **and speed (EDIT)**:

```
>>> my_list = ['apple', 'carrot', 'chicken', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'ham']
>>> labels = ['Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Meat']
>>> [f"{l}: {v}" for l, v in zip(labels*(len(my_list)//len(labels)+1), my_list)]
['Fruit: apple', 'Vegetable: carrot', 'Meat: chicken', 'Fruit: orange', 'Vegetable: broccoli', 'Meat: ham']
```

Other version (does not create a second list):

```
>>> L = len(labels)
>>> [f"{labels[i%L]}: {v}" for i, v in enumerate(my_list)]
['Fruit: apple', 'Vegetable: carrot', 'Meat: chicken', 'Fruit: orange', 'Vegetable: broccoli', 'Meat: ham']
```

Benchmark:

```
>>> my_list = my_list * 1_000_000
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: [f"{l}: {v}" for l, v in zip(labels*(len(my_list)//len(labels)+1), my_list)], number=10)
5.743572215003951
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: [f"{labels[i%L]}: {v}" for i, v in enumerate(my_list)], number=10)
8.350919869997597
```

Comment: What is the F Index coming from `[f"{label` ? I can't seem to use that in python 3.7. `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Is it possible to incorperate any formating to those, such as `print('{:15} : {:3}'.format( < insert one-liler here>))` ??

Comment: @Laylor010 This is a f-string, or [formatted string litteral](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals). It's been introduced in Python 3.6 and it's a concise form of `str.format`. `f"{l}: {v}"` is equivalent to `"{l}: {v}".format(l=l, v=v)`. You can add format options (fill, align, sign, width, precision, type).

Comment: Thought I deleted that comment, that was resolved quickly. thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

A good option to accomplish this is a dictionary:

```
#from collections import OrderedDict

my_list = ['apple', 'carrot', 'chicken', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'ham']
labels = ['Fruit', 'Vegatable', 'Meat']
length_of_labels = len(labels)

#my_dictionary = OrderedDict()
my_dictionary = {}

for i,l in enumerate(my_list):
    my_dictionary[l] = labels[i%length_of_labels]

for d in my_dictionary:
    print('{:10} : {:10}'.format(d,my_dictionary[d]))
```

OUTPUT

```
apple      : Fruit
carrot     : Vegatable
chicken    : Meat
orange     : Fruit
broccoli   : Vegatable
ham        : Meat
```

The dictionary will let you call `my_dictionary["Apple"]` to get the label for `"Apple"` and similarly for all of your other foods.  The part with `[i%length_of_labels]` ensures that if you get to the end of your `labels` list, it will start back at the start.

Comment: In this fashion, would also need collections.OrderedDict() `my_dictionary = OrderedDict()` to maintain printing order.

Comment: Good call, I'll add that in

Comment: @Laylor010 Actually, as of Python 3.7 normal dictionaries will keep their order.  So for a simple example like this a normal dictionary will do

Comment: True, 3.6 and earlier will need the OrderedDict though. Also, in the event any data from the two lists going into the dictionary might possibly hold like key:value pairs, the dictionary won't store the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> my_list = ['apple', 'carrot', 'chicken', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'ham']
>>> labels = ['Fruit', 'Vegatable', 'Meat']
>>> [f'{labels[idx % 3]}\t{value}' for idx, value in enumerate(my_list)]
['Fruit\tapple', 'Vegatable\tcarrot', 'Meat\tchicken', 'Fruit\torange', 'Vegatable\tbroccoli', 'Meat\tham']
```

Comment: What is the F Index coming from `[f{labels` I can't seem to use that in python 3.7. `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: The feature is called [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). It is supported for Python 3.6 and above. You do need the quotes: `f'text {expression} more text'`.

Comment: Sorry, was missing the brackets. Is it possible to incorporate spacing format into that one-liner, or would it need to be broken apart first? This wont work, but something like `print('{:15} : {:3}'.format([f'{labels[index % 3]}, {value}' for index, value in enumerate(my_list)])` ??

Comment: Yes, try this: `print(['{:15} : {:3}'.format(labels[index % 3]}, {value}) for index, value in enumerate(my_list)])`

Comment: Get unresolved references on idx and value without the f'' that way.  Tried this:  `print(['{:15} : {:3}'.format((labels[idx % 3]), ({value})) for idx, value in enumerate(my_list)])` but got `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to set.__format__`

Comment: thanks, I was able to modify that a little bit to get it working. I updated main post with result. Thanks again